# Метки gridview при пустом списке

Tags: php, yii2, yii, gridview

Я использую стандартный [GridView](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-grid-gridview) для вывода таблички. При пустом списке элементов выводится надпись задаваемая параметром `emptyText`. С этим все в порядке. Но! Заголовки столбцов при пустом списке меняются на значение параметра `attribute` для конкретного столбца... Вместо того чтобы оставаться той меткой которая указана в модели методом `attributeLabels`. Например:

```
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => new ArrayDataProvider(['allModels' => $items]),
    'columns' => [
        [ 'attribute' => 'name' ],
        [ 'attribute' => 'phone' ],
    ],
    'emptyText' => 'пусто'
]);
```

Если элементы есть то отображается так (в соответствии с метками в `attributeLabels` модели):

```
| Имя  | Телефон      |
|------|--------------|
| Тест | +79081234567 |
```

Но если элементов нет то отображаются названия атрибутов:

```
| name  | phone |
|-------|-------|
|     пусто     |
```

Как этого избежать? Указывать дополнительно параметр `label` у каждого столбца? Но это дублирование меток уже указанных в `attributeLabels` :( Не очень хотелось бы...

P.S. Логично было бы помимо `dataProvider` указывать где-то класс модели отдельно и чтобы он уже подтягивал метки оттуда даже если элементов нет... Но я не нашел такой возможности. Кроме разве что `filterModel`, но тогда добавляются инпуты фильтрации, а мне они не нужны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У `ArrayDataProvider` можно задать свойтво `modelClass`. Пропишите там название своего класса.

Comment: Во!!! То что я и хотел!

Answer (score 1):

Данная ситуация возникает потому, что GridView использует массив данных, а не массив моделей. Если использовать ActiveDataProvider, то заголовки столбцов будут отображаться корректно даже если ничего не найдено.

Comment: Это вариант, но что если мне не нужен ActiveDataProvider? В этой табличке у меня выводятся обычно всего несколько штук моделей и мне удобнее (хотя бы для отладки) видеть их массивом, а не запросом. Нет ли другого решения?

Comment: Не вызывать GridView, если $items пустой.

Comment: Нет, заголовок таблицы все равно должен отрисовываться.

Comment: Я бы отказался от Array, потому что этот провайдер требует загрузки всех данных в память и это снижает его эффективность. В случае с Active для отладки можно получать массив моделей вот так $posts = $provider->getModels();

Comment: Я же сказал - моделей всего несколько штук в этой таблице отображается. Нет там никакого снижения эффективности. ActiveDataProvider нужен там где моделей хотя-бы за сотню - когда уже нужно разбиение на страницы, фильтрация, сортировка и т.п.

Comment: Пока у меня больше нет вариантов. Если Array вместо Active используется только для удобства отладки, то можно его оставить на время отладки, а потом заменить на Active